# Как установить composer в LAMPP?

Tags: php, composer, xampp

Здравствуйте. Как установить composer в LAMPP на Linux? Если можно наиболее полную инструкцию. В Windows, при установке XAMPP надо было указать, где находится php драйвер, как это делается в Linux я не знаю.

Comment: первый совет: пользуйтесь репозиториями дистрибутива. не устанавливайте всякие там `*ampp`. всё необходимое есть в репозиториях: и apache, и php, и mysql, и perl. не создавайте себе проблем «на ровном месте» своими же руками.

Comment: Композер никак не связан с lamp, ему нужен только бинарник php и некоторые расширения. Процесс установки с официального сайта должен работать как часы.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/442500/178576

Answer (score 1):

1. воспользуйтесь мануалом с офф сайта https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-osx, особенно обратите внимание на строку
   `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`
2. так же у вас есть простая возможность скачать composer.phar и пользоваться им таким способом
   `php composer.phar update`