# Установка composer и Laravel на XAMPP Linux

Tags: php, laravel, composer, xampp

Всем привет!
Кто может поделиться пошаговой инструкцией как установить на XAMPP под Linux Mint 17.2 composer для установки Laravel?
Спасибо!

Comment: `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вынесено из комментария:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | \
  sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```